# requirejs ignore my requirejs.config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

here is my files struct:

```
ex/js/prpr.js
ex/test-requirejs.html
```

test-requirejs.html

```
  <script>
    requirejs.config({baseUrl: "js"})
    require(["prpr.js"], function () {
      var uri = new Uri("http://baidu.com")
    })
  </script>
```

when i `google-chrome /home/roroco/Dropbox/jss/ro-js/ex/test-requirejs.html` I get error

```
file:///home/roroco/Dropbox/jss/ro-js/ex/prpr.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Uncaught Error: Script error for "prpr.js"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
```

my requirejs version is 2.3.2
how to make requirejs.config work?

**update**

even I use

require.js

```
requirejs.config({baseUrl: "js/"})
require(["prpr.js"])
```

and tag:

```
<script src="./require.js" data-main="./main.js"/>
```

I get same error

Comment: Don't write require in script tag..... instead make separate file. and initialize it using data-main attribute....

Comment: @Kenny I update my question, even I use require.js, the same error is raised

Comment: requirejs.config => require.config

Comment: use require.config({})..... instead of requirejs.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However I don't know your file structure But from your question I am assuming that it is like this

- Project Folder

  - test-requirejs.html
  - main.js
  - require.js
  - js

    - prpr.js

If this is your folder structure

then in test-requirejs.html, script tag should be

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
```

Your  **main.js**

```
require.config({
        "baseUrl": "js"
    })

    require(["prpr"],function(){
    });
```

I have tested this by my own and its working

Comment: I'm very sure this error exist, see my [full demo](https://github.com/roroco/test-requirejs-config)

Comment: Remove .js extenstion from require(["prpr.js"])...... It should be require(["prpr"])